# preserve numerical class when exporting a data frame with write.table() in R

Tags: r, write.table

I have two data frames I merged:

```
df1 <- read_csv("df1.csv", col_types = cols(Date = col_date(format = "%d/%m/%Y")))
df2 <- read_csv("df2.csv", col_types = cols(Date = col_date(format = "%d/%m/%Y")))
df3 <-left_join(df1, df2, by = 'Date', df1 = TRUE)

write.table(df3, file = "df3.csv", sep = "," )
```

df3>
[image: Q3]

before I export the df3, all my columns are numerical but after exporting they are transformed into logical so I do the following:

```
df3 <- read_csv("df3.csv", col_types = cols(Date = col_date(format = "%d/%m/%Y")))

cols <- c(sapply(df3, is.logical))
Q[cols] <- lapply(df3[cols], as.numeric)
```

But once I export it one more time, the data frame goes back to logical and that affects my following functions.

My doubt is:

1. How can I preserve the numerical class of my columns when exporting a data frame.

Comment: A CSV file is just a text file that does not contain column type information. You need to take care when importing the data to make sure the columns are read as you intend. Rather than storing data as a CSV, you could use an RDS file to store the R object itself. See `?readRDS`. But basically you can't use CSV.

Comment: To add, with text files, R will scan to determine data types. If entire column is blank with NAs, R will default to the lowest storage type: logical, according to its coercion rule of atomic classes: logical < integer < numeric < complex < character. Save with R serialization types (RData or RDS) to retain meta information like data types. (Also, binary format is faster to read/write than text).